# I am unable to retrieve the Many-To-One column while fetching records

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

Here is entity code

```
 @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.id)
      @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
      user_id: number;
```

I've tried this code

```
PropertyEntity.find({relations: ['user_id']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity definition is wrong. `@ManyToOne` decorator should decorate a field that is of type `User`. Try this:

```js
@ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.id)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' }) // This would be the join column name in the table in Postgres
user: User;

/**
 * The following is optional. You can omit this property and it would still 
 * work. Keeping this helps if you want to insert this record without 
 * providing the entire `User` entity. This also allows you to find using 
 * `user_id`.
 *
 * Note: Change the type if it is not `varchar`.
 */
@Column({ type: 'varchar' })
user_id: string;
```

Then when you want to find, you should use the below syntax in your `find` method:

```js
find({ relations: ['user'] });
```